# EJB Façade calling methods in another EJB

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, ejb, facade

I am trying to invoke methods of an EJB Facade from another but I am facing some errors then I ask your help to do this in correct way. I will post the current code to try to explain.

The JSF Bean front end object starts the sequence of calls:

```
@RequestScoped
public class FrontEndBean {

    @EJB
    private SomeFacade someFacade;

    public String submit() {
        MyEntityObject myobj = new MyEntityObject();
        myobj.setStringProperty("somestring");
        someFacade.businessMethodOnSomeFacade(myobj);
    }

}
```

The first Façade source looks like this:

```
@Stateless
public class SomeFacade {

    @EJB
    private AnotherFacade anotherFacade;

    public void businessMethodOnSomeFacade(MyEntityObject obj) {
        if (obj.getStringProperty() != null) {
            anotherFacade.businessMethodOnAnotherFacade(obj);
        }
    }

}
```

And the Another Façade:

```
@Stateless
public class AnotherFacade {

    public void businessMethodOnAnotherFacade(MyEntityObject obj) {
        if (obj.getStringProperty().equals("somestring")) { // null pointer exception

        }
    }

}
```

Is it correct? Can I invoke an EJB façade from another using @EJB? If not, What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: What errors are you facing?

Comment: In businessMethodOnAnotherFacade Im getting null pointer exception just like in comment.

Comment: Lets focus in the way of instantiate the Facade and take the null pointer exception to the next step.

Comment: You are instantiate Facades in correct way. I don't see anything unusual here. The only reason for null might be that you share the object obj and reset stringProperty to null.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, if the instantiations are correct then I will dig deeper about the NPE (I will treat like another subject) and post my comments here just for curiosity.

Comment: Agree, I would focus on state of property `stringProperty` - suggest inspecting it / watching it in a debugger because something may be setting it to null. There is also the possibility that the `getStringProperty()` method contains logic you are not expecting - such as returning `null` in certain conditions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes everything is correct. You can inject whatever EJBs you like.